# Cannot show scene with Cocos2D when using UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, uiview, sdk, cocos2d-iphone

I'm new to Cocos2D but am having serious issues when trying to load a cocos scene in one of the UIViewControllers mixed with other normal UIKit UIViewControllers.

My project uses a UITabBarController to manage four view controllers. Three are normal UIKit view controllers while one of them I want to use cocos2D for (to draw some sprites and animate them).

The following is what I've done so far. In the applicationDidFinishLaunching method, I initialize cocos2D to use the window and take the first tabbarcontroller view:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
  if( ! [CCDirector setDirectorType:CCDirectorTypeDisplayLink] ) {
    [CCDirector setDirectorType:CCDirectorTypeDefault];
  }

  [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setPixelFormat:kPixelFormatRGBA8888];
  [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];
  [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDisplayFPS:YES];

  [[CCDirector sharedDirector] attachInView: window];   

  [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview: tabBarController.view];
  [window makeKeyAndVisible];  
}
```

Then in the third UIViewController code (where I want to use cocos2D) I do this (note: the view is being loaded from a NIB file which has a blank UIView and nothing else):\

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
  CCScene *myScene = [CCScene node];

  // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
  MyLayer *myLayer = [MyLayer node];

  // add layer as a child to scene
  [myScene addChild: myLayer];

  [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene: myScene];  
}
```

However all I see is a blank white view and nothing else. If I call the following in viewdidLoad:

```
  [[CCDirector sharedDirector] attachInView: self.view];
```

The app crashes complaining that CCDirector is already attached. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see it makes sense why the crash is happening.  You have already called `attachInView` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and then you are trying to attach it again in `viewDidLoad`.  Looking at your code there's a few things that don't really make sense to me.

If I understand your intention correctly you should only need to call `attachInView` in `viewDidLoad` but you could leave the `CCDirector` setup calls where they are inside `applicationDidFinishLaunching`

> I initialize cocos2D to use the window
>   and take the first tabbarcontroller
>   view:

This part confuses me a bit.  Where do you want the Cocos2D view to end up.  Who do you want to child it to and do you want it to have any children views?